# my GET variable is being escaped?

Tags: php, apache, http, get, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm really confused here, can someone explain this to me?

request:
`http://example.com/test.php?var=String's`

```
$a = $_GET["var"];
$b = "String's";

echo $a . "<br/>";
echo $b . "<br/>";

$output = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
$output = mysql_real_escape_string($b);
echo "<hr/>";
echo $a . "<br/>";
echo $b . "<br/>";
```

result:

```
String\'s
String's
----------------
String\'s
String's
```

Could someone explain to me not only why my GET variable is being transformed like this, but how I can remove this behavior such that my input is exactly as it was sent? I'm having an issue where my SQL wrapper passes this through mysql_real_escape_string() and ends up being `String\\\'s` :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called ["magic quotes"](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: Doh! I didn't think of that. I hate when the simple things get by me. +1

Comment: Wow I clearly didn't take my coffee this morning... There's even problems in my example's work.

Answer (score 2):

You can **and should** disable magic quotes.

**prefered mode**
set them off in php.ini

**.htaccess mode**
<sub>add this to your htaccess file</sub>

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

**php5 runtime mode**

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
?>
```

**php4 runtime mode**

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
?>
```

Welcome to the `magic_quotes` hater's club! :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have magic quotes turned on. This automatically escapes GET, POST and COOKIE data. Magic quotes is bad and should not be relied upon to properly escape data.

If you have access to php.ini, you can [turn magic quotes off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

If you don't, you can run [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the data to remove the slashes. In order to make your code portable, you should first check `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` to see if it is turned on and only then run stripslashes. In this way, if you move your code to a server that has magic quotes turned off, your code will still work.

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $a = stripslashes($_GET["var"]);
}
else $a = $_GET["var"];
```